# How does size( ) works in java's ArrayList class?

Tags: java, arraylist, performance

So, in order to get the most efficient code, I really wanted to know how does the `size()` method in Java `ArrayList` work... Does it count every element, going through all the positions, like a simple list? or does it just gets the size by the last index registered?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it gets a variable that stores the size.

Comment: Read the source Luke: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.SubList.size%28%29

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't really think of that... Just read the javadoc for arrayList and forgot to check the source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never hurts to look in the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.size%28%29):

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

It returns an instance variable - pretty damn fast.

Comment: You are referencing the OpenJDK source and not the official Sun source

Comment: @SteveKuo - OpenJDK *is* effectively Sun source (which is closed and cannot be posted to a public forum).

Answer (score 2):

As of the latest Java7, it does a little more than read a member field value:

```
public int size() {
    checkForComodification();
    return this.size;
}

private void checkForComodification() {
    if (ArrayList.this.modCount != this.modCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ArrayList` there's an `int` attribute for storing the current size (say, called `size`). Clearly, calculating the size of an array list should be an `O(1)` operation, for efficiency. Even in a data structure such as a `LinkedList` (a double-linked list) the size is kept updated in an attribute, to avoid having to calculate it each time it's needed. To see it more clearly, take a look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) in OpenJDK, there you'll find this:

```
 /**
  * The size of the ArrayList (the number of elements it contains).
  *
  * @serial
  */
  private int size;

 /**
  * Returns the number of elements in this list.
  *
  * @return the number of elements in this list
  */
  public int size() {
      return size;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code for `ArrayList`, the `size()` method returns a private variable named `size`, which is just a counter that is incremented on each `add`.

Answer (score 0):

It reads a field variable. Java 1.6's `ArrayList.size()`:

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this list.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in this list
 */
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```