# Original array size and list.size returns different values

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

[image: check out the size and the element count in debug window]

I was creating a RecyclerView in which the adapter gets items from a JSON file which I created in assets folder.I am using GSON to convert it to list of objects. while running the app was crashing because of **Nullpointer Exception**. while debugging I saw that the array size is not matching the original element count.Can anybody share their views on this?

I had to add **list.size-1** in the getItemCount() instead of just adding **list.size** in order for my app to work.

in the screenshot at bottom of page the arry size is 8 and opened up array shows only 7 elements, which should never happen.

Comment: Trying to understand why you thought taking a screen shot was simpler than copying/pasting...

Comment: @anomeric I can't understand how the size of actionEvents became 8 . that's why a screenshot.According to me this is not about my code at all. the size should be 7 there is only 7 elements in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, This is because of an extra comma after the last object in my JSON array which I tried to parse. While converting it to list of objects because of the comma GSON thinks there is one more object coming.Removed the comma and everything worked fine.seeing the array in debugging window makes no sense , got the app working but still didn't understand how it returned 8 for a 7 element array.

Found from [Perception's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512528/3309470) that size returns an instance variable.have to search in GSON source to know how it does the parsing